# Find the immediate occurrence before the matching regex pattern

Tags: regex, grep

MY server file looks like below

STRING X

```
TYPE:

08:23:37.253 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.iso.decoder.ISODecoder - [MTI=""] - [STAN=""] - [REF=""] - 
TYPE: 0800
DE   7     DATE10: Mon Jul 05 08:23:52 PKT 2021 -> '0705082352'
DE  11    NUMERIC: 000012 -> '000012'


TYPE:

08:23:37.253 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.iso.decoder.ISODecoder - [MTI=""] - [STAN=""] - [REF=""] - 
TYPE: 0800
DE   7     DATE10: Mon Jul 05 08:23:52 PKT 2021 -> '0705082352'
DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011'
```

Now the problem is that I want to extract only the following part
STRING Y

```
TYPE: 0800
DE   7     DATE10: Mon Jul 05 08:23:52 PKT 2021 -> '0705082352'
DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011'
```

I am using this regex to find only the above part but it highlights the entire file.
The process is that that I want to find the pattern `DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011'` and find the preceding first TYPE only.

My regex pattern:

```
TYPE((.|\n)*)DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011'((.|\n)*)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add your used command to your question (no comment).

Comment: At the end, I have mentioned my regex pattern.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://regex101.com/r/JFCNip/1

Comment: @MDR this matches from the first TYPE but i only want to match the TYPE above the line DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011 which TYPE: 0800

Comment: Still not sure.  Maybe https://regex101.com/r/YTqeKE/1? Or even https://regex101.com/r/SIfMOm/1?  If you could edit your question and say given string X I want to match Y line in the middle it would help clarify.

Comment: Mention string x and string y in the question

Comment: @MikeM

TYPE: 0800 right above. I have edited the question. My bad.

Comment: Perhaps: https://regex101.com/r/E3Y1gs/1?

Comment: @MDR Stop answering in comments. If you have an answer, post it.

Comment: No.  As it's unclear what the OP wants.  The request (for this and his other question) are too ambiguous for me to answer fully.

Comment: @MDR Then ask questions to get clarification - that's what comments are for.

Comment: @MDR
Thankyou your second link works. Selecting of 1st group using ( solved the problem

Comment: @HamzaAzam you're welcome.  I've posted it as an answer for you.

Comment: I see you accepted an answer that will apparently work on the regex101.com web site. Was that what you wanted rather than an answer using a Unix tool? If not then you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For text of:**

```
TYPE:

08:23:37.253 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.iso.decoder.ISODecoder - [MTI=""] - [STAN=""] - [REF=""] - 
TYPE: 0800
DE   7     DATE10: Mon Jul 05 08:23:52 PKT 2021 -> '0705082352'
DE  11    NUMERIC: 000012 -> '000012'


TYPE:

08:23:37.253 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG c.iso.decoder.ISODecoder - [MTI=""] - [STAN=""] - [REF=""] - 
TYPE: 0800
DE   7     DATE10: Mon Jul 05 08:23:52 PKT 2021 -> '0705082352'
DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011'
```

**Try:**

`(TYPE: \d+.*\n.*\n.*DE.*?NUMERIC:.*?011'$)`

**Matches:**

```
TYPE: 0800
DE   7     DATE10: Mon Jul 05 08:23:52 PKT 2021 -> '0705082352'
DE  11    NUMERIC: 000011 -> '000011'
```

**Demo and explanation:**

- https://regex101.com/r/E3Y1gs/1

Comment: *\n.*\n only looks two lines above but in some cases its not fixed two lines. Can be two or more. Can i do that?

Comment: I rarely use grep so I can't comment further on flexible multi-line searches using that.  I wouldn't want to give the incorrect advice.

Comment: A bit more fiddling.  I don't think it's perfect by any means: https://regex101.com/r/FvsREq/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
/^.*?numeric.*$/gmi
```

Comment: But this doesn't match the requested STRING Y (three lines) the OP asked for.